# okhttp и restful

Tags: java, rest, okhttp

скажем имеется некий сервис

```
@Path("/printing")
public class PService {
    @POST
    @Path("/check")
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String test(@QueryParam("t") String txt) {
        return "Вы отправили: " + txt;
    }
}
```

когда с браузера или с Postman стучаю по УРЛ **127.0.0.1:8080/project/printing/check?t=qweqweqwe**
я честно получаю ответ.
а вот с Okhttp не понимаю как надо достучится... точнее ретурн то возвращает только **либо нулл либо ничего**
в качестве источника взял [отсюда](https://howtoprogram.xyz/2017/01/14/how-to-post-with-okhttp/)

Comment: думал нашел решение, но оказывается нет... вопрос открыт

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать [`HttpUrl.Builder.addQueryParameter`](http://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/HttpUrl.Builder.html#addQueryParameter-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) для построения URL.